# how to show the following output in wpf datagrid depending on a condition

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, wpf-controls

I am displaying the Processing Time data in a datagrid as follows

[image]

using the following statement

```
  var duration_query = this.db.Events
                       .Where(p => ID.Contains(p.ServerID) &&
                       p.Type == "Complete" && 
                      // fromDP and toDP are name of DataPicker control
                       (p.Date >= fromDP.SelectedDate.Value && 
                        p.Date <= toDP.SelectedDate.Value))
                       .GroupBy(p => p.Duration)
                       .Select(g => new
                       {
                       Duration = g.Key,
                       serverID = g.Count()
                       })
                       .OrderBy(x => x.Duration).ToList();

  dgProcessingTime.ItemsSource = duration_query.ToList();
```

XAML

I have used Layout Transform to rotate the datagrid header.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgProcessingTime" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false">     
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="timeColumn" Header="Time in seconds" Binding="{Binding Path=Duration, Mode= OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="amountColumn" Header="Amount of Events" Binding="{Binding Path=serverID, Mode= OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

How to display the same result like this ? in multiples of 10 ( for the Time in seconds?)

**<10 <20 <30 <40**

and count the Amount of events for the above condition?

do i have to alter the select statement which i have used above, so that it groups and counts the amount of events <20 for example ?

Comment: So would events less than 20 return events less than 10 as well (cumulative sum)?

Comment: no only between 10 and 20 @cvraman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but just give this a try:

```
  var duration_query = this.db.Events
                       .Where(p => ID.Contains(p.ServerID) &&
                       p.Type == "Complete" && 
                      // fromDP and toDP are name of DataPicker control
                       (p.Date >= fromDP.SelectedDate.Value && 
                        p.Date <= toDP.SelectedDate.Value))
                       .GroupBy(p => (((int)(p.Duration / 10)) + 1)*10)
                       .Select(g => new
                       {
                       Duration = g.Key,
                       serverID = g.Count()
                       })
                       .OrderBy(x => x.Duration).ToList();

  dgProcessingTime.ItemsSource = duration_query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, could u pls explain, what does (((int)(p.Duration / 10)) + 1)*10) exactly does ? does it displays the sum between 20 and 30 and then display it or the cumulative sum less than 30

Comment: Let's say the duration is `56`. It will be divided by `10`, so it will return `5.6` and then it will get cast to `int`, so we will end up with `5`. As you can see this just cuts off the last digit. Then we add `1` to it, and multiply it by `10`, in the end we get `60`. It only shows the ones that are less than `60` and greater than or equal to `50`.

Comment: you mean values between >= 50 and <=60 ?

Comment: thanks this works great, but the result begins from 20. how to begin from 10

Comment: It is `50 <= value < 60'. The result starts from 20 because there's nothing between `0` and `10`. To add each duration, you will have to add them either to the `duration_query.ToList()`, or add them on your WPF `DataGrid` columns. Check the biggest duration, let's say it is `30`, then add the relevant columns to the `DataGrid`: `10`, `20`, `30`, `40`.

Comment: yes, the list starts from 10, and then 11, 12 and so on. one last question, why it is not including the values of 60 in this case. sorry for troubling you.

Comment: No worries. The reason is when you divide `60` by `10`, you get `6`, you add `1` to it and get `7`, then multiply it by `10` and you will get `70`. It's all about the group limits. The group is defined as less than `60`, so `60` is not less than `60`, hence ends up in the group `less than 70`.

Comment: If you want to add `60` to it too (to change the group definition to something like `50 < value <= 60`), you can use something like `p => (p.Duration % 10) == 0 ? ((int)(p.Duration / 10))*10 : (((int)(p.Duration / 10)) + 1)*10` I haven't tried it though, just writing it here.

Comment: I will try and get back. thank u so much for taking the time to explain

Comment: so it like this, when Duration % 10 is True, perform this (p.Duration / 10))*10 else perform (p.Duration / 10)) + 1)*10 ?

Comment: When `Duration % 10 is equal to 0` do `A`, else do `B`.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample code that groups items between ranges :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace TestWPFApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var eventList = new List<Event>();
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 9, Name = "Test", ServerId = 1 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 8, Name = "Test", ServerId = 2 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 5, Name = "Test", ServerId = 3 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 10, Name = "Test", ServerId = 4 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 12, Name = "Test", ServerId = 5 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 15, Name = "Test", ServerId = 6 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 20, Name = "Test", ServerId = 7 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 22, Name = "Test", ServerId = 8 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 23, Name = "Test", ServerId = 9 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 25, Name = "Test", ServerId = 10 });
            eventList.Add(new Event() { Duration = 30, Name = "Test", ServerId = 11 });

            var ceilings = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 };

            var grouped = eventList
                .GroupBy(item => ceilings.First(ceiling => ceiling > item.Duration))
                .Select(g => new { Duration = "<" + g.Key, serverID  = g.Count()});

            dgProcessingTime.ItemsSource = grouped.ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ServerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This would give the result below :
[image: Result]

You would need to change your posted query from the `GroupBy` clause onwards

Comment: var ceilings = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 }; you are explicitly giving it from code behind, but the "Time in seconds" in my application is generated on runtime. how to add this in GroupBy ?

Comment: Well you will have to guess the biggest possible duration and create an array that has all the possible durations for this approach. Feasible if it's not a problem.

Comment: The ceilings are **duration ranges** which I have hardcoded for conveniance. Practically, you would be initializing this array at run time.